# How to pass component name as argument and receive it in function

Tags: angular, arguments, components

I need to pass a component name as argument to a function and receive it and use it. But only string is received. Below is the code

```
(click)="this.myapp.openModal('AddContactModelComponent','xl')"
```

I am receiving it here to use as component

```
 openModal(component:any,size:string) {
    // const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(
      component,
      {
       size: size, 
      });
      this.modal_title ='test';
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **are** passing in a string as the `component` argument (`'AddContactModelComponent'` in your example).

You will most likely need a mapper that `openModal` can use like so

```
openModal(componentName: string, size: string) {
  const mapper = {
    'AddContactModelComponent': AddContactModelComponent,
    'AnotherString': AnotherComponent,
  };

  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(
    mapper[componentName],
    {
      size: size,
    });
}
```

Then you can call it as desired in your template

```
(click)="this.myapp.openModal('AddContactModelComponent','xl')"
```